# Is this a problem with the Django tutorial or a package problem, or is it me?

Tags: python, django, package

I'm using Ubuntu 10, python 2.6.5

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02
I followed all of the steps using cut-and-paste.
The following directory structure was automatically created:

```
bill@ed-desktop:~/projects$ ls -l mysite  
total 36  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bill bill     0 2010-09-01 08:18 __init__.py  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bill bill   546 2010-09-01 08:18 manage.py  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bill bill 20451 2010-09-01 18:50 mysite.wpr  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bill bill  3291 2010-09-01 08:18 settings.py  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bill bill   127 2010-09-01 11:13 urls.py  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bill bill    97 2010-09-01 08:20 views.py
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
import sys
print sys.path

from mysite.views import hello
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

pylint produces this error: Unable to import 'mysite.views'

## views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")


bill@ed-desktop:~/projects/mysite$ python manage.py runserver 

Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.2.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Which resulted in:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
   1. ^hello/$ 
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Why does view.py which is in the main directory contain the following?

```
from mysite.views import hello
```

There is no subdirectory 'views'.  Although I'm familiar with using packages, I've never had the need to create my own so I'm a bit confused.  I would have thought that `from views import hello` would be correct.

The step-by-step tutorial looks straight forward and I haven't seen anyone else come across this problem so I'm a bit perplexed what I've done wrong.

Comment: Probably completely incorrect, but should `r'^hello/$'` be `r'^/hello/$'` ?

Comment: @dbr: no, the syntax is correct.

Comment: The tutorial tells you to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`

Comment: Yes, I missed this in the tutorial: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ 

and  (r'^$', hello), does work if I use only http://127.0.0.1:8000.  

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you see 404 error, because you don't have the default handler, add to url patterns something like this:

```
('^$', views.default )
```

and probably you need to add the web application path to the sys.path variable to be able to 'see' your modules:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path_to_site)
```

Comment: When I added sys.path.append("..") the mysite.view import error went away. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your actual question is.

You've requested the root page, `\`, but have only defined a URL for `\hello\`, so obviously Django can't find what you've requested. If you want your `hello` view to match against the site root, do this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', hello),
)
```

I don't understand the question about the `from mysite.views import hello`. This will work if the parent of `mysite` is on the Python path.